# parse error in else

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
 maxZyklus :: UntereGrenze -> ObereGrenze -> (UntereGrenze,ObereGrenze,MaxZyklaenge)
 maxZyklus m n = if m > n then (m,n,0) else if m == n then 
                         (m,n,length(func m)
                         else 
                         (m,n,length(func m)
 type UntereGrenze = Integer
 type ObereGrenze  = Integer
 type MaxZykLaenge = Integer
```

i get a parse error on input `else` that second one Where could the problem be ?

Comment: Are your parens balanced in your code?  They're not balanced in your sample here.

Comment: At least in this sample, the second `if then else` is superfluous, as both the `then` and `else` clauses have the same expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing two `)`'s.

```
(m,n,length(func m)
```

should be

```
(m,n,length(func m))
```